# mongoDBのfield(documents)をcsvに出力したい

Tags: mongodb

mongodb初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

公式ドキュメント: よりexportのやり方

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Qiitaの記事に掲載されているexportのやり方
https://qiita.com/masarufuruya/items/33fbe059229230c8fc0c

以上を参考にしexportを試みました。
さくらのレンタルVPS上のmongodbから収集したツイートをcsvファイルに
出力したいです。

db名はkenkoで、collections名はtweetdataになります。

自分のmongodbの構造
    db(_kenko)
     　　|--collections (tweetdata)
         　　　　　　|--documents

以下のように実行しました。

> mongoexport --db [;kenko] --collection [;tweetdata] --type=csv --fields _id,date_time,host,time --out ~/ubuntu/kenko.csv

エラーの内容を参考にしつつ、英語版stackoverflowを参照したところ、ある記事でcollectionsの頭が_(underscore)か数字がないと出力されないと記載されていました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557908/mongodb-change-db-name

そこでクローンして名前の修正を行いました。

```
2018-01-18T20:47:18.867+0900 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14
```

ですが同じエラーが発生しています。

どうすればcsvファイルを出力できるでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

公式ガイドには次のように書いてありますが、

> mongoexport must be run directly from the system command line.

mongoシェルから`mongoexport`コマンド実行しているということはないですか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。mongoシェルの外から実行したところ解決しました。（汗ありがとうございます。気をつけます・・・。